# build loadmore listview with stream

Tags: dart, flutter

I built a base paginatied listview in flutter using future and it seems to work well:

```
  Future loadNext() async {
    if (!isPerformingRequest && isLoadMore) {
      setState(() => isPerformingRequest = true);

      int page = (objects.length / widget.pageSize).ceil() + 1;
      List<T> fetched = await widget.pageRequest(page, pageSize);

      if (fetched == null ||
          fetched.length == 0 ||
          fetched.length < pageSize) {
        this.setState(() {
          isLoadMore = false;
        });
      }

      if (mounted) {
        this.setState(() {
          //this.addObjects(fetched);
          objects.addAll(fetched);
          isPerformingRequest = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Now i want to using stream and streambuilder instead but i dont know how to write a condition to stop the load more, How to know which page is the last?